# ASP.NET 5 Website (Razor)

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

I'm building an angular app powered by WEB API in VS2015 and ASP.NET 5.

In the previous version of ASP.NET it was possible to serve CSHTML pages in lieu of HTML pages, without having to construct MVC Controllers and Routes.  An example was if you created an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) project.

Basically you could go to localhost/index.cshtml
and assuming had had something like @DateTime.Now.ToString() on the page it would return a white page with the date on it.

I want to serve my client markup via CSHTML as opposed to HTML static filed because I'd like to leverage some of the convenient server-side stuff like TagHelpers.

Is this possible as of Beta8 for ASP.NET 5?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to translate every page to string. I Used this for email templates.
You can setup your own route to an generic controller or create your own [middleware](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html).

With this code you van generate a view to string

```
 RenderViewToString(@"/Views/Email/ActivateEmail", new ActivateEmail() { Emailaddress = user.Email, Callback = callbackUrl })

 public async Task<string> RenderViewToString<TModel>(string view, TModel model)
    {
        var viewEngineResult = _compositeViewEngine.FindView(_actionContext, view);
        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        {
            Model = model
        };
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                _actionContext,
                viewEngineResult.View,
                viewData,
                new TempDataDictionary(new HttpContextAccessor(), new SessionStateTempDataProvider()),
                sw,
                new HtmlHelperOptions());
            await viewEngineResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah i thought about this - but would rather know if support exists within the framework.  I imagine something like app.UseRazorPages() in startup.cs